# JavaScript - Filter thousands of keys thousands of times

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, ecmascript-6, javascript-objects

I have chart on my web app, and each time I recieve a new information I need to update the chart.

Right now I am doing simulation so I backtest (in json) with about 100000 datas (but could be millions if browser and hardware could handle it).

For this reason I need my code to be as optimised as possible.

I have object like this:

```
var trades = {"1515867288390":{price:"10", quantity:"500"},
            "1515867289541":{price:"9", quantity:"400"},
            "1515867295400":{price:"11", quantity:"750"},
            "1515867296500":{price:"7", quantity:"1100"},
            ...}
```

Each time I scan one object inside trades, I want to get the medium price for the last X seconds, so I have a $.each(trades, getAverage...)

```
getAverage = function (trade_time) {

var total_quantity = 0;
var total_trade_value = 0;
var startfrom = trade_time - duration;

Object.keys(trades).forEach(function (time) {
    if (time < startfrom)
        delete trades[time];
});

$.each(trades, function (key, value) {
    total_quantity += parseFloat(value.quantity);
    total_trade_value += (value.price * value.quantity);
});

var average = (total_trade_value / total_quantity);
return average;
}
```

Average execution time was about 7.5s for 80000 trades.

Not bad I guess but the problem is I need duration in `var startfrom = trade_time - duration` to be adjustable, this is causing problem cause my getAverage function removes all element based on startfrom, itself depending on duration, so if at start duration = 10, and then duration changes to 20, get average will only be able to look back for the last 10 seconds anyway.

A solution would be to duplicate the array to keep a "full" copy, but my function would then itterate all elements each time, and will be way slower.
Second option I have tried was not deleting the item and using:

```
Object.keys(trades).filter(t => t>=startfrom).forEach(function (time) {
    var value = trades[time];
    total_quantity += parseFloat(value.quantity);
    total_trade_value += (value.price * value.quantity);
});
```

It was about 300 times slower, so really bad choice, I was wondering what you would think about?

Thank you.

PS: I was thinking about using array as my key are always numeric (timestamp), but I would end up with millions of empty index if I use array, wouldn't this slow performances again?

Comment: Why dont you use an array instead of a lookup object?

Comment: Suggest using zone.js to avoid performance issue in browser

Comment: @JonasW. because my keys are millisecond timestamp, and I recieve between 1 to 10 informations by second, so I would end up with millions of empty index, wouldn't this slow the process even more?

Comment: When you receive `new information`, do you get all of the data again, or just changes that you append to the existing data? If you get everything, can you not calculate the averages on the server side and cache them for the duration of the time period?

Comment: Why are you using `$.each` which is almost certainly slower than using an equivalent built-in method? You've already done `Object.keys(trades)`, so store the keys and re–use them. Where does `type` in `delete trades[type]` come from?

Comment: @user3119384 thats true but i dont mean a sparse array. I mean `[{ ts: 1515876... }, { ts: 1515877... },...]`

Comment: @fubar Informations are coming from websocket api that is not mine so I can't edit serverside, and I recieve trade by trade, but I saved a lot of them to backtest

Comment: @RobG yes you are right it will get faster this way but I still won't work with adjustable duration, and type is from my code, I tried to simplify it here so it's more understandable but forget to delete it, done now

Comment: Since objects aren't ordered, you can't "go back" in any meaningful sense, you have to get the keys into an array and sort them, that way you can get the keys within a certain time range. It would be better to put your data into an array like `[{time:1515867288390, price:"10", quantity:"500"},...]`. If pushed in sequence, they'd already be sorted so much easier to go back and forward for transactions in a range.

Comment: You could also use multiple service workers, because they might actually use multiple CPU-cores. = Performance * whatever cores you have.

Comment: @JonasW. I don't understand what you mean, for me array would be great beaucause I could do for (t=startfrom, t<trade_time, t++} but if it is as in your exemple, t will be 0,1,2,3 and it won't work right?

Comment: @RobG: There is a big assumption in *«If pushed in sequence, they'd already be sorted»*

Comment: @RobG Ohh so you mean using array for all, sounds good, but then how would I 'for (t = startfrom, t < trade_time, t++}'?

Comment: If I also make a big assumption... If there is NOT two trades exactly at the same millisecond... The array key could be the time. Then... It would order itself. like `data[1515867296500]={price:"7", quantity:"1100"}` But if there is a second one at the exact same time... It will over write the first.

Comment: Performance aside, if `getAverage()` destroys the dataset then it can be run again, therefore (i) don't destroy the dataset, or (ii) work with a copy of the dataset, or (iii) fetch the dataset afresh each time `getAverage()` is called.

Comment: In your current object the time is used for the property name, so a second trade with the same time value will overwrite the first, i.e. it can't have duplicate time values or two trades with the same time. Last one wins.

Comment: @Roamer-1888 well seen, typo while simplifying the code, it's not destroying the dataset but only the values wich key is < startfrom

Comment: @RobG: so my array key idea is as good as the actual object structure. ;)

Comment: Won't help in your logic, but a good step for performances would be to move it in a webWorker, which would be directly connected to the socket. This way you will even be able to mess with memory garbage without polluting your main thread and UX.

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette There is very little possibility for 2 trades at the same time, and even if it happens it doest matter as it won't be significant for the average. Using array with timestamp as key would be great but and I would end up with millions of empty key, then 'for (t = startfrom, t < trade_time, t++}' will be even slower right?

Comment: @user3119384 Why empty keys?

Comment: let say there is a trade at 1515867288000 and the next one at 1515867289000, this is 1k empty key in the array before the next trade, so trades would return [1515867288000  => {price:5, quantity: 400}, 1515867288001=> null, 1515867288002=> null, .........., 1515867288000 => {price:5, quantity:300}]

Comment: If `trades` is the dataset then `delete trades[time];` (partly) destroys the dataset.

Comment: @user3119384: You're right... I tryed. Moreover, the time integer is too big to be an array key. So that is an explored idea.

Comment: @Roamer-1888 You are right, the idea is to keep it small so each won't take too long, but it will work only if 'duration' is always the same, when you make it bigger, trades won't contain the data anymore if it has been deleted before :/

Comment: `Object.keys(trades).reduce(...)` would allow you to loop through the dataset once, non-destructively.

Comment: @Roamer-1888 Good idea, but the problem is even if it does one loop only, this will loop the entire trades object, everytime there is a new trade, so the loop duration is exponential and at the end the execution is taking way too much time

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette too bad, I hoped you would have came with a working array solution to skip empty value indexes :/ Now I have no idea how to handle the problem

Comment: "everytime there is a new trade"!!! I didn't understand that from the question. Did I miss it? That makes a massive difference to the whole approach.

Comment: @Roamer-1888 in the question I've written 'Each time I scan one object inside data' and data shoul've been 'trades' (fixed now), as trades represent a backup of what the websockets sends in about 12 hours, and that's about 80-100 thousands trades

Comment: OK, so does the websocket receive the data *en-block* or just updates?

Comment: @Roamer-1888 updates, it recieves trades one by one inside a json object

Comment: A websocket is stateful, yes? Therefore transform each trade as it arrives and push it onto an array (or splice it into the array if the trades might arrive out of order). By hook or by crook, make sure the array is kept in timestamp order. Then, when your non-socket code fetches data from the socket (as `trades`) and works out an average, the data you want will always be at one end of the array. As soon as a non-qualifying trade is reached, the calculation can cease (break out of the loop).

Comment: @Roamer-1888 that's very smart, I will try to put this on practice thank you.

Comment: Looking fwd to learning how it goes.

Comment: @Roamer-1888 it was successful, thank you so much

Comment: I'll write this up as an answer. I will also toss in another idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a couple of (closely related) ideas.

**Idea 1**

As each trade arrives, push it onto an array (or splice it into the array if the trades might arrive out of order). By hook or by crook, make sure the array is kept in timestamp order. Then, when your non-socket code fetches data from the socket (as trades) and works out an average, the data you want will always be at one end of the array. As soon as a non-qualifying trade is reached, the calculation can cease (break out of the loop).

**Idea 2**

Similar to Idea 1 but instead of maintaining an array of raw trades, store a series of "stats objects", each representing a timeslice - maybe as little as 15 seconds worth of trades but possibly as much as five minutes worth.

In each stats object, aggregate `trade.quantity` and `trade.quantity * trade.price`. This will allow the average for the time slice to be calculated but more importantly will allow two or more time slices to be combined, by simple addition, before calculating the average.

This can be achieved with two inter-dependent constructors :

```
/*
 * Stats_store() Constructor
 * Description: 
 *    A constructor, instances of which maintain an array of Stats_store() instances (each representing a time-slice), 
 *    and receive a series of timestamped "trade" objects of the form { price:"10", quantity:"500" }.
 *    On receipt of a trade object, an exiting Stats_store() instance is found (by key based on timestamp) or a new one is created,
 *    then the found/created Stats_store's .addTrade(trade)` method is called.
 * Methods: 
 *    .addTrade(timestamp, trade): called externally
 *    .getMean(millisecondsAgo): called externally
 *    .timeStampToKey(timestamp): called internally
 *    .findByKey(key): called internally
 * Example: var myStats_store = new Stats_store(101075933);
 * Usage: 
 */
const Stats_store = function(granularity) {
    this.buffer = [];
    this.granularity = granularity || 60000; // milliseconds (default 1 minute)
};
Stats_store.prototype = {
    'addTrade': function(timestamp, trade) {
        let key = this.timeStampToKey(timestamp);
        let statObj = this.findByKey(key);
        if (!statObj) {
            statObj = new StatObj(key);
            this.buffer.unshift(statObj);
        }
        statObj.addTrade(trade);
        return this;
    },
    'timeStampToKey': function (timestamp) {
        // Note: a key is a "granulated" timestamp - the leading edge of a timeslice.
        return Math.floor(timestamp / this.granularity); // faster than parseInt()
    },
    'findByKey': function(key) {
        for(let i=0; i<this.buffer.length; i++) {
            if(this.buffer[i].key === key) {
                return this.buffer[i];
                break;
            }
            return null;
        }
    },
    'getMean': function(millisecondsAgo) {
        let key = this.timeStampToKey(Date.now() - millisecondsAgo);
        let s = { 'n':0, 'sigma':0 };
        let c = 0;
        for(let i=0; i<this.buffer.length; i++) {
            if(this.buffer[i].isFresherThan(key)) {
                s.n += this.buffer[i].n;
                s.sigma += this.buffer[i].sigma;
                c++;
            } else {
                break;
            }
        }
        console.log(c, 'of', this.buffer.length);
        return s.sigma / s.n; // arithmetic mean
    }
};

/*
 * StatObj() Constructor
 * Description: 
 *    A stats constructor, instances of which receive a series of "trade" objects of the form { price:"10", quantity:"500" }.
 *    and to aggregate data from the received trades:
 *       'this.key': represents a time window (passes on construction).
 *       'this.n': is an aggregate of Σ(trade.quantity)
 *       'this.sigma' is an aggregate of trade values Σ(trade.price * trade.quantity)
 *    Together, 'n' and 'sigma' are the raw data required for (or contributing to) an arithmetic mean (average).
 *    NOTE: If variance or SD was required, then the store object would need to accumulate 'sigmaSquared' in addition to 'n' and 'sigma'.
 * Methods: 
 *    .addTrade(trade): called externally
 *    .isFresherThan(key): called externally
 * Example: var myStaObj = new StatObj(101075933);
 * Usage: should only be called by Stats_store()
 */
const StatObj = function(key) {
    this.key = key;
    this.n = 0;
    this.sigma = 0;
}
StatObj.prototype = {
    'addTrade': function(trade) { // eg. { price:"10", quantity:"500" }
        this.n += +trade.quantity;
        this.sigma += +trade.quantity * +trade.price;
    },
    'isFresherThan': function(key) {
        return this.key >= key;
    }
};
```

Usage

```
// Initialisation
let mySocket = new WebSocket("ws://www.example.com/socketserver", "protocolOne");
const stats_store = new Stats_store(2 * 60000); // 2 minutes granularity

// On receiving a new trade (example)
mySocket.onmessage = function(event) {
    let trade = ....; // extract `trade` from event
    let timestamp = ....; // extract `timestamp` from event
    let mean = stats_store.addTrade(timestamp, trade).getMean(10 * 60000); // 10 minutes averaging timeslice.
    console.log(mean); // ... whatever you need to do with the calculated mean.
    // ... whatever else you need to do with `trade` and `timestamp`.
};
```

A certain amount of flexibility is provided by choosing the values passed to `new Stats_store()` and `.getMean()`. Just make sure that the first value is smaller than the second.

Light testing (on medium performance computer, Chrome browser under Win7) of (2) **[here](https://jsfiddle.net/ngcwcwsh/)** indicates that:

- performance should be at least adequate for the kind "trade" rate you are talking about (100,000 in 12 hours or 140 per minute).
- memory usage is spikey but doesn't leak in the short term. You probably need a "housekeeper" process to sweep up the tail in the longer term.

Finally, ideas (1) and (2) are not completely different.

As (2)'s `granularity` constant passed to `new Stats_store()` gets smaller, so the behaviour of (2) will tend towards the behaviour of (1).

Answer (score 1):

Maybe a low level implementation is faster. For that you could create a new `Buffer` to store your data:

```
 const buffer = new ArrayBuffer(10 ** 4 * (3 * 3));
```

To actually work with the buffer we need a view onto it. I think a int32 is sufficient to store timestamp, amount and data ( in 3 * 3 bytes). All that can be bundled in a class:

```
 class TradeView {
  constructor(buffer, start, length){
   this.buffer = buffer;
   this.trades = new Uint32Array(buffer, start, length);
  }
  //...
}
```

Now to add a trade, we go to the related position, and store the data there:

```
   //TradeView.addTrade
   addTrade(index, timestamp, {quantity, price}){
    this.trades[index * 3] = +timestamp;
    this.trades[index * 3 + 1] = +price;
    this.trades[index * 3 + 2] = +quantity;
  }
```

Or to get it:

```
 //TradeView.getTrade
 getTrade(index){
   return {
     timestamp: this.trades[index * 3],
     price: this.trades[index * 3 + 1],
     quantity: this.trades[index * 3 + 2],
  };
}
```

Now we need to fill it with the objects data (this is slow, so it should be called when you receive a small chunk from the backend):

```
 const trades = new TradeView(buffer);
 let end = 0;

 function loadChunk(newTrades){
   for(const [timestamp, data] of Object.entries(newTrades))
     trades.addTrade(end++, timestamp, data);
}
```

Now the real cool part: A buffer can have multiple dataviews. That means, we can "filter" the trades array without copying the data. For that we just need to find the starting index and the ending index:

```
 //TradeView.getRangeView
 getRangeView(startTime, endTime){
   let start = 0, end = 0;
   for(let i = 0; i < this.trades.length; i += 3){
      if(!start && startTime < this.trades[i])
         start = i;
      if(this.trades[i] > endTime){
         end = i - 3;
         break;
      }
  }
  return new TradeView(this.buffer, start, end - start);
}
```

Comment: If we are in a browser environment, then I guess you meant *ArrayBuffer*, and `10 ** 10` is an invalid length and beware it is `TypedArray(buffer, start, length)`, not `..., end)`. Otherwise, good idea.

Comment: The idea is genius, if I understand it as I think it should work well, but I think the solution given as a comment by Roamer-1888 is more simple and adapted to my problem.

Comment: @user3119384 the strategies can be applied to this answer too

Comment: @JonasW. Sounds better, though are you sure about your getRangeView function? As I said, the constructor is  `TypedArray(buffer, start, length)` while if I read correctly (didn't ran so I may be wrong and hold my upvote for nothing) you are setting `length` as end offset , which will be wrong in most cases.

Comment: @kaiido thanks again. You are absolutely right, havent tested it either ...

Answer (score 0):

what if you convert it to **one loop, instead of the two loops in your code(one for deleting and the other for iterating)**, like this

the inverse of if condition

```
Object.keys(trades).forEach(function (time) {
    if (time >= startfrom) {
      value = trades[type];
      total_quantity += parseFloat(value.quantity);
      total_trade_value += (value.price * value.quantity);
    }

});
```

Comment: For a particular trade, the OP wants to get the trades within x seconds of the entry and average the price (where x is adjustable). This just iterates over the all the trades.

Comment: This might be a bit faster but won't fit my problem for the reason said by @RobG

Comment: @user3119384 instead of the two loops, one for deleting and the one for iterating, you can the above single function, since it is not deleting the array items, you can further check for say 20 sec or more

Comment: The solution you offer is similar to the second test I tried, the idea is good and would work for a small objet, but if you don't delete elements, javascript will itterate each element in the array each time getAverage is called, on what I tried it ended up being about 300 times slower for a 1000 trades dataset.